# How to access members of a service from HTML View?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular 2 and am not sure which way I should go to update the view.

Example: 
I got two components, user and main.

User component gets a user list from UserService. The component is reading all users on initialization from this service and sets a components member to the list of users.

If another user gets selected, the component just transfes the value (id) to UserService, which stores the user object in a member called "selected". UserService has got a method getSelected() to return the selected user.

As far as good, it is working (by the way, how to make private/public members/methods in Type Script?)

Now I would like to display the selcted User in main component. 
How do I display it, that every update of the select gets delegated through the service and catched by the main component.

Example Code in user controller to select the user

```
onChange(event) {

        this._userService.select(event.source.value);

    }
```

In user service I store it like this:

```
select(userId: number) {
        for (const user of this.users) {
            if (user.getId() === userId) {
                this.selected = user;
            }
        }
    }
```

main component got

```
getUser() {
        return this._userService.getCurrent();
    }
```

At HTML I tried this

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="center center">    
    <div>selected User: {{getUser()}}</div>
</div>
```

But it does not work. What is the best way in angular2/typescript?

Should I direktly access the service in my HTML? What would you prefer/suggest?

Refards, 
n00n

Comment: Maybe there was an issue in your ```select``` function. It should work the way you did it. Try this sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfhmut

Comment: You can directly access service's variable from HTML by service's `object` like `<div>selected User: {{ _userService.getCurrent() }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish your task:

Just create a Subject variable in your service like this:

```
public selectedUser$ = new Subject<User>();
```

When a user will selected just emit a value by above observable like this:

```
onChange(event) {
  this._userService.selectedUser$.next(event.source.value);    
}
```

In your second component you need to subscribe your subject to get value like this:

```
this._userService.selectedUser$.subscribe(user => {
  console.log(user);
})
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: The second way is parent child communication by input. Is your both component in parent child relationship.
By the way first way will work in every case. Whether it is in parent child relationship or not

Comment: This is completely new for me. What is the $ in this.service.selectedUser$.next(user); for?

Comment: $ in variable at last position indicates that variable is a observable. I Updated my answer for your convenience.